# Firefox input orange outline

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I've got 2 Inputs a slider and a number input the both sync each other via JavaScript. The border of my number input is grey, when I click it, it's purple. I don't have any outlines my problem is, when I change the slider the number input updates too, but then there is an outline an orange one. I've got this problem only in Firefox in chrome it looks perfect.

```js
let range = document.querySelector(
  "input[type=range]"
);
let number = document.querySelector(
  "input[type=number]"
);
range.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  number.value = e.target.value;
});
number.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  range.value = e.target.value;
});
```

```css
:root {
 --first-color: #ffffff;
 --second-color: #5e17a2;
 --third-color: #707070;
 --fourth-color: #cccccc;
}
.number {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 2px solid var(--fourth-color);
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: text;
  color: var(--third-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.number:focus {
  border: 2px solid var(--second-color);
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pvi flex">
  <input type="range" min="0.25" max="5" value="1" step="0.25" class="slider">
  <input type="number" value="1" class="number" placeholder="1,0" min="0">

</div>
```

Comment: please add a code example. preferably with codeasandbox or jsfiddle

Comment: can you please add the code snippet to understand better what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: I did add it the problem is that on firefox there is a outline if I change the slider value which updates the number input. The Number input got this outline it is orange

Comment: @Itamar No need for third party code sites when you can embed a runnable snippet from right within the question. In fact, using such services without a [mcve] in the question is forbidden.

Comment: you are totally currect

Comment: Sorry for that I am new to stackoverflow and in general new to coding

Answer (score 2):

Set the step on the number input to match the range input. The default step value is 1, so Firefox is highlighting the fact that it seems invalid.

```js
let range = document.querySelector(
  "input[type=range]"
);
let number = document.querySelector(
  "input[type=number]"
);
range.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  number.value = e.target.value;
});
number.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  range.value = e.target.value;
});
```

```css
.number {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 2px solid var(--fourth-color);
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: text;
  color: var(--third-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.number:focus {
  border: 2px solid var(--second-color);
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pvi flex">
  <input type="range" min="0.25" max="5" value="1" step="0.25" class="slider">
  <input type="number" value="1" class="number" step="0.25" placeholder="1,0" min="0">

</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove this sign that it is invalid?

Comment: @PhilippManhart You can wrap it in a form tag with the `novalidate` attribute. But adding the step to the input seems easier.

Comment: Okay, I'm coding a Google extension and both inputs do the same but I think it is annoying to get exactly 1 at the slider input if there are no steps, that's why I added them but the user should have the option to input exact values via the number input like 1.01. In the end the js code will only look at the number input because if the user just use the slider the number's input would change also.